# What does int arr[10]{} this declaration in C++ means?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
int fr[10]{}
```

I seen this declaration in C++ is this 1-D array or it is 2-D. Which type of declaration it is?

Comment: Should be easy enough to find out if compile this code?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I found it to be 2-D but don't know about such declaration.

Comment: It's same as `int fr[10];`, but with the elements zeroed. `{...}` or `= {...}` can contain a list of initializers for individual elements, and the remaining elements are zeroed (since the list is empty, all elements are zeroed here).

Comment: @usaka *I found it to be 2D* Not sure how you decided that, because it's 1D. E.g. `fr[0]` is OK, but `fr[0][0]` is an error.

Comment: Same as `int fr[10]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };`

Answer (score 0):

C++ since its version 11 has introduced in its standard the use of curly brackets for the initialization of objects.

Here are some examples:

```
MyObjects obj {};
MyObjects obj {firstParameter};
int array[10] {};
```

In the latter case, it refers to the fact that it will contain 10 elements initialized as zero in it. In the case of the standard types you will see what was written in the memory cell first

[Here you will find a precise explanation of all this](https://blog.quasar.ai/2017/03/05/cpp-braced-initialization)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I took the liberty of modifying the answer to make it clearer. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: wrong. they are initialized. That's what `{}` does. In the case of arrays, like here it performs aggregate initialization.

Comment: Yes, it's true. They are zeroed. I've edited it again so it doesn't get confusing

Comment: @StellarClown 